# Python and new instance

Tags: python

Although i'm familiar with other programming languages, I'm struggling to understand my code in python and why my class properties aren't reset when i reassign the class... eg. I have a method in a notify class

```
def send(self):
    for service in self.hosts:
      # func = getattr(self, service)
      for host in self.hosts[service]:
        try:
          if service == 'xbmc':
            self.xbmc(host)
          elif service == 'growl':
            self.growl(host)
          elif service == 'prowl':
            self.prowl(host)
        except:
          print "Cound't connect " + host.find('ip').text + " For " + service
```

As you can see, this will iterate through each service (so keep in mind I have 3 xbmc's)

so take xbmc for an example, the method is

```
def xbmc(self, host):
  x = Xbmc(host)
  x.notify(self.title, self.message)
```

under other languages, if i would assign x again, it would be a completely new fresh object, but this doesnt seem to be the case with python...

I will place snippets off my xbmc class to explain the issue.

```
class Xbmc:
  hosts = []
  def __init__(self, host = None):
    self.setHosts(host)
    self.server = Hosts().getHostsByService('xbmcserver')

  def setHosts(self, host = None):
     ...alot of elif...
     elif type(host).__name__ == 'Element': # this code is the one that is in effect from my notify class
       self.hosts.append(host)
     ...more elif...
     print self.hosts # for debugging
```

now that the code is there, when i initiate my notify to send. the output shows:

```
[<Element 'host' at 0x7fdda19d0d10>]
XBMC 192.168.1.10 Failed To Connect
[<Element 'host' at 0x7fdda19d0d10>, <Element 'host' at 0x7fdda1955090>]
XBMC 192.168.1.10 Failed To Connect
XBMC 192.168.1.20 Failed To Connect
[<Element 'host' at 0x7fdda19d0d10>, <Element 'host' at 0x7fdda1955090>, <Element 'host' at 0x7fdda19553d0>]
XBMC 192.168.1.10 Failed To Connect
XBMC 192.168.1.20 Failed To Connect
XBMC 192.168.1.21 Failed To Connect
```

its clear that when i append the host, that its never actually a new instance but always appends to what was already there... I assumed x = Class() would initiate a New Instance? if i do

```
self.hosts = [host]
```

then obviously i dont get the undesired effect, but it would be good too know why my initial approch doesnt work or how to overcome it. Do we need a reset method? or is there actually a way to create a new instance off a class? or is there something wrong with my code? thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The problem is caused, because the class property `hosts` is mutable (list), so appending to it will influence every instance.

### Solution

The solution is to change the class property into instance property:

```
class Xbmc:
    # <--- (no more "hosts" here)
    def __init__(self, host = None):
        self.hosts = []  # <--- we are initializing "hosts" property here now
        self.setHosts(host)
        self.server = Hosts().getHostsByService('xbmcserver')
    # and so on...
```

Comment: But i thought because its in the class scope and its a property off a class, then that should be irrelevant?

Comment: @Edhen: I do not follow. It is a property of a class, yes. It is in a class (although accessible both from instances, as from "the outside"). And no, it is not irrelevant - mutable is mutable, and if you change it, it has new value.

Comment: I just put hosts there because its easier too read to see what properties my class has... Thank's for the answer but it still gets me as too why hosts isn't acting like a public property when its in that classes scope

Comment: EXACTLY RIGHT... it is a property of a class.... if i did php $x = new Xbmc($hosts).. doesn't matter whats in those properties, every time i create a new instance, those properties will be reset unless they were static.....

Comment: after some tests, it turns out your right about it being mutable, it just overthrows me to exactly why (something i will need too read up on) but your answer is valid and correct

Comment: @Edhen: if you try to _assign_ to a class attribute on an instance of the class, you create a _new_ attribute on the instance. However, if you _modify_ a **mutable** class attribute, it will change the attribute in place. Remember, this is all syntactic sugar for `dict`, so it's basically the difference between `d['a'] = 1` and `d['a'].append(1)`. The first assigns a new value, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Xbmc:
  hosts = []
  def __init__(self, host = None):
    self.setHosts(host)
    self.server = Hosts().getHostsByService('xbmcserver')
```

Should be

```
class Xbmc:
  def __init__(self, host = None):
    self.hosts = []
    self.setHosts(host)
    self.server = Hosts().getHostsByService('xbmcserver')
```

The first version creates a list shared between all Xbmc instances. The second creates a list for each one.

Comment: Exactly. As I mentioned the issue is caused because the `hosts` is actually a mutable - it would not be caused, if it would be `None`, overwritten on a per-instance basis.

Comment: so the technically, the ones outside are static properties?

Comment: @Edhen, technically they are class properties. But for most intents and purposes, that's the same as a static property in other languages.